# Hook a function with uneditable method in PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to know if this is possible.

Imagine that I am using a PHP library Class which I can not modify. However I want to hook to its method somehow, that whenever it's called, my custom code executes.

For example:

```
<?php

function uneditable() {
    // does something
}

// my code:
if(<uneditable is called>){
    // do this
}
```

Is it possible in PHP somehow?

Note: I'm trying to do this with WordPress, as I have to detect execution of some method in a third party plugin which doesn't provide hooks to the endpoint that i'm trying to hook into. I don't want to edit the plugin itself as it will get updated anytime and my code will be gone.

Thank and Regards.

Comment: There are no native language constructs for this. If the plugin does not provide hooks, you can't really do much.

Comment: Sometimes you do need to modify the plugin files. You can simply use a `do_action('your_action_name')` inside that uneditable method you are speaking of and use that action as `add_action('your_action_name', 'your_custom_callback')` inside your theme or custom plugin files. In this way we will have a very little to loose and easy fix if the plugin is updated and remove your modification.

Comment: yes this is what i was planning too, and to request the plugin author to include this line in next update too

Comment: Make this question specific to your situation and Wordpress, as there’s no solution in PHP, but there may be in Wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

As it is wordpress you can use the **Wordpress hook**.

Here is an example.

```
<?php

 /**
  * Define the action and give functionality to the action.
  */
 function uneditable() {
   do_action( 'uneditable' );
 }

 /**
  * Register the action with WordPress.
  */
 add_action( 'uneditable', 'uneditable_hook' );
 function uneditable_hook() {
   echo 'This is a custom action hook.';
 }
```

You can read more about [add_action](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/) and [do_action](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_action/)

Comment: If anything it’s a Wordpress *hook*, not a webhook. That term has a specific, different meaning.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is abstract method in abstract class. That will force the child class to implement the method.

```
abstract class A {


abstract function a() {}

}

class B extends A {

function a () {


// write your code here.
}
}
```